# Javascript newline will not shift data to new line with a join statement

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi I tried several methods to get my data to display on new lines. The \n does not work, `<br>` does not work, and according to Google the answer is `\n`, but it does not work?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
data.dateFrom = _.pluck(value.leave_form, 'dateFrom').join('\n');
```

Comment: _.pluck() returns an array if I'm not mistaken. Running ["moe", "larry", "curly"].join('\n') in the console produces a string as I expect you are looking for. Can you confirm what  _.pluck() is returning?

Comment: I don't think .concat() is the solution as it produces an array. Form the docs.... "The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays."

Comment: Pluck is returning an array of the dates, but show it in a string on my page. But I would like to put the dates below each other

Comment: Can you provide a code example? Does the string not contain the new lines?

Comment: You're trying to solve too many problems at once. Forget JavaScript. First, hand-code a straight HTML page, optionally with CSS, that renders the the way you want. _No JavaScript!_ Add that HTML/CSS page to your question as a "snippet". (Use the <> button at the top of the edit box.) Then, _after_ you've done that, add a second snippet with your attempt at JavaScript code to generate the appropriate HTML.

Comment: _“Pluck is returning an array of the dates, but show it in a string on my page.”_ - in what _context_? “Normal” HTML? `pre`? Formatted using `white-space`? …?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `white-space: pre-wrap`

```
#string {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/NDfool/pen/MrWyzo

```js
let value = {};
value.leave_form = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}]

let data = {};
data.dateFrom = _.pluck(value.leave_form, 'name').join('\n');

document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = data.dateFrom;
```

```css
#string {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p id="string"></p>
```